# How do you set gboard as the default spell checker in Android v12

Tags: samsung, gboard, spell-check

I have a Samsung S22 running Android v12 on it. I can't seem to set the default spell checker as GBoard. There does not seem to be an option to change this from Samsung Keyboard to GBoard. The moment I click on Samsung Keyboard, it seems to take me to the settings page for the Samsung Keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this article from Android Police](https://www.androidpolice.com/change-samsung-keyboard-gboard-default-galaxy-phones/), it seems you may be able to set Gboard as the default during the installation of the app.

If you've already installed it though, [Samsung](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00079092/) specifies these steps to change your default keyboard (and therefore spell checking service):

Open the **Settings** app and select **General Management**.

From there, select **Keyboard list and default**, then tap **Default keyboard**.

There, you should see Gboard listed and be able to select it.